# STM32 HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM;

Tags: stm32, can

I want to connect two stm32 via CAN but I have the following problem,
I have this configuration

[image]

and this code:

[image]

but i have this error, HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM:

[image]

I can't see any signals on my oscilloscope. I want to see the TX signal and what it sends via CAN.

Answer (score 0):

Your time quanta (tq) settings do not make any sense at all. Your tool appears to call tq "time". ("How many 'time' do you want?" thx ST great tool...) The tq settings might not be the only problem in your program, but it's one you need to fix first.

A CAN bit is divided into a sync segment, a propagation segment and two equally large phase segments around the sample point. Recommended best practice for most baudrates is to place the sample point at 87.5% of the total bit length.

The most common bit timing setting is therefore to use 1 tq sync, 11 tq propagation, 2 tq phase segment1 and 2 tq phase segment2. The sample point will then end up at 1+11+2 = 14 out of 16 tq = 87.5%.

So step 1 is to read the documentation of your unhelpful tool to get a translation of "bit segment 1" and "bit segment 2" into standard CAN terminology as used in this answer. And then configure accordingly.

For a baudrate of 500kbps = 2000ns bit length indeed. But you'll want a tq to be a 16th of that, if you follow my advise for tq configuration. 2 * 10<sup>-6</sup> / 16 = 125ns.

Resynchronization jump width of 1 tq is fine for 500kbps. This is a specified inaccuracy tolerance - for higher baudrates you can tune this up to 2 or 3.